# Dynamics CRM 2011 Plugin Deploy Error

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I'm developing a custom plugin for CRM. When I deploy plugin to CRM on Virtual PC, I get the error below.

> Error registering plugins and/or workflows. Legacy plugin steps are
>   only supported in Pre-validation and Post-operation stages

How can I resolve this error ?

Comment: The error is when you register the step or when you upload the plug-in?

Comment: Hi @Sxntk 
Thanks for your response,

Plugin already registered on solution, when I deploy crmpackage, visual studio gives this error.

Comment: Error means you cannot register CRM 4.0 plugins in Pre-Operation (20) stage, only 10 (Pre-Validation) and 40 (Post-Operation) is allowed. You have an upgraded organization, I suspect ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @Alex has said, it looks like you are using the CRM 4 sdk to develop your plugins. I would recommend using the CRM 2011 SDK in order to not have to rewrite your plugins once you upgrade to 2013 or above. Here's the link:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24004

Comment: Hi @BlueSam, I'm using DynamicEntity to develop the plugin

Comment: Correct. That is the class name in the CRM 4 SDK that represents a CRM record. Since 2011, it is now Entity. Here's a post about the changes from CRM 4 to CRM 2011 to know about: http://weblogs.asp.net/gayanperera/5-syntax-changes-in-dynamics-crm-2011-plugins

Comment: Thank you all for your answers